What made the question on Sellae off-topic
Dorsum sellae, tuberculum sellae and sella turcica which of the 3 is referred to by the adjective sellar? was closed as off-topic as it had nothing to do with Neuroscience or Psychology.
@BryanKrause points out in the comments that

a neuroanatomy question should surely be on topic here.

So what made this question off-topic?

But you voted for closure too?

Yes @AliceD but I raised this question in response to the queries in the comments by Bryan Krause

As pointed out in Wikipedia,

the sella turcica (Latin for Turkish seat) is a saddle-shaped depression in the body of the sphenoid bone of the human skull

Also in Wikipedia

The dorsum sellae is part of the sphenoid bone in the skull.

particularly, in relation to the sphenoid bone, it is horizontally at the exact center, and vertically at the level of the posterior clinoid process.
And

The tuberculum sellae (or the tubercle of the sella turcica) is a part of the sphenoid bone that is an elevation behind the chiasmatic groove.

So they are all parts of the sphenoid bone.
As far as I am aware, and I could be wrong — hence the need for community decision on closures — while the pituitary gland is located within the sella turcica for example, the sella turcica is not strictly part of neuroanatomy, which is a study of the structure and organization of the nervous system which in turn involves the brain, spinal cord and related neural networks throughout the body.
While some parts of the nervous system sits within specific parts of the human skeleton, the skull and the spine, just as with the rest of the skeleton, is anatomy, but not neuroanatomy.
Not only that, but the original unedited question was in relation to a physician/surgeon. So, with everything as a whole, the question is off-topic here and should be asked in MedicalSciences.SE
The question has since closure, been edited to relate to neuroanatomists and therefore it may now be on-topic but I will leave that for the rest of the community to decide bearing in mind my view on the delineation of neuroanatomy.

Wouldn't the Neurocranium be studied by Neuroanatomy?

@GeorgeNtoulos If you apply that logic in my view, 90% of human anatomy could be under the umbrella of neuroanatomy. Dermatomes relate to the anatomy of the vertebral regions of the spine. The nerves travel throughout the body, the organs and within the skin. Is the whole body neuroanatomy?

I don't find it problematic for 90% of human anatomy to be under the umbrella of neuroanatomy. Neuroanatomy certainly includes the nerves that travel throughout the body. Anything that is functionally (and immediately; without another structure intermediating) related to these nerves should logically be a part of neuroanatomy.

In Greece especially in Athens we study the Neurocranium (at least I did before quitting Medicine and converting to Law) in a module named Neuroanatomy. And I am sure in Brazil the Neurocranium is studied in Neuroanatomy classes.
